# Snowflake Clone

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a cloned schema of QA environment and moved it to DEV environment in SNOWFLAKE.

My requirement that I currently working on is, in future if any table gets updated with the data's in original schema or if any new table added to the original schema, it should automatically get updated to the cloned schema in DEV environment as well.

Will that be possible to make it as required?

Answer (score 1):

Clone does not replicate the changes automatically.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone#general-usage-notes

For your requirement, you can go with the Replication feature.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/replication-intro

Comment: for table level we can able to replicate the changes automatically by creating a stored procedure and a task for that SP by giving each and every table name separately. So, I hope there must be an option to achieve the same amongst the schema level (all tables)